# jQuery fly out menu - How to separate two different items with line

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a fly out menu similar to the one on this page http://jc-designs.net/demo/flyout.html

When hovering over the main tabs, is it possible to insert a line between one more items on this menu?

So for "Home" instead of:

About this template here
Flash
jQuery

It would be:

About this template here 
--------------------------------------
Flash
--------------------------------------
jQuery

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Now, what's your relevant HTML? And what CSS (or jQuery) have you attempted, and where are you stuck?

Comment: The code is literally on the site I linked to, thanks who ever down voted though...

Comment: Your relevant code should be included in your question, why do you expect us to follow random links around the internet to provide you with help? We *like* to help, we *enjoy* helping; but we'd sincerely appreciate it if you'd try and help *us* to help *you*. For further information, please consider reading the '[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)' (a Stack Overflow resource explaining why we need your code in your question, and what code to *put* in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to do it in css adding something like

```
.listTab li{
   border-bottom: 1px;
   border-style : dashed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom border to each item:

```
var sel = "ul > li > ul > li";
$(sel).css("border-bottom", "black solid 1px");
```

You can also conditionally not add this styling to the last element (`:last-child`)